# PHP / MySQLi syntax with HTML table

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for my `sql` table to perform a sort, but only if the search form has not been sent.

Can someone help me with the correct syntax please?

```
 <th><?php if(!isset($_POST['search'])) { echo "<a href='?orderby=FirstName&order="$firstOrder";' }?>">First Name</a></th>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<th><?php if(!isset($_POST['search'])) { echo "<a href='?orderby=FirstName&order=".$firstOrder."'>First Name</a>"; }?></th>` chheck and let me know

Comment: What error you got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look around quotes changes. Do like below:-

```
<th><?php if(!isset($_POST['search'])) { echo "<a href='?orderby=FirstName&order=".$firstOrder."'>First Name</a>"; }?></th>
```

Comment: That works... thank you. The issue i have now, is that it doesn't show a title when the search is used. Any idea how i should still show the column titles ?

Comment: @Tatws24 please ask a new question with providing your full code and what you want. Right now it's impossible to suggest without checking your code.